# how to validate input fields to a total page count in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I currently have a form where users are able to enter in start and end page numbers of a document they want to specify. Users are also allowed to create more rows of start and end page as well. One of the validations that i want to put in place is to calculate that the total number of pages that the user selected equals the total number of pages of the document they are entering page numbers for. I'm having trouble with the total page validations. Not really sure where i should put the logic in...

HTML:

```
<form name="pageForm" ng-submit="submitPageForm(pageForm.$valid)" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3" ng-repeat="file in pages.items">
        <label for="start">Pages </label>
        <input type="number" name="startPage" class="form-control" id="start" ng-model="file.startNumber">
        <label for="end"> - </label>
        <input type="number" name="endPage" class="form-control" id="end" ng-model="file.endNumber" ng-change="autoStartPageNumber($index)">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <label for="totalPage">total: {{totalPage}}</label>
        <input type="number" ng-model=totalPage>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <a href="#" ng-click="addRow()">Add another document</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="pageForm.$invalid">Done</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{result}}
</form>
```

controller:

```
    $scope.pages = {
    items: [{
        startNumber: 1,
        endNumber: ''
    }, {
        startNumber: '',
        endNumber: ''
    }]
};
$scope.totalPage = 10;
$scope.autoStartPageNumber = function(index) {
    if (index + 1 < $scope.pages.items.length) {
        $scope.pages.items[index + 1].startNumber = $scope.pages.items[index].endNumber + 1;
    }
};
$scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.pages.items.push({
        startNumber: $scope.pages.items[$scope.pages.items.length - 1].endNumber + 1,
        endNumber: ''
    });
};
$scope.submitPageForm = function(isValid) {
    // check to make sure the form is completely valid
    if (isValid) {
        $scope.result = 'form is valid!';
    } else {
        $scope.result = 'form is invalid!';
    }
};
```

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zomdar/60f7v8h4/6/)

EDIT:
For example if total page count is 10...then i want the user to be able to select options like 1 - 5 and 6 - 10 for it to be valid. if the total page count is off for instance like 1 - 3 and 4 - 11...then i want to throw an error

Answer (score 1):

You can make the total page count a field calculated by you instead of getting it from the user. In that way you don't have to do validations for it.

**JS**:

```
$scope.autoStartPageNumber = function(index) {
    if (index + 1 < $scope.pages.items.length) 
        $scope.pages.items[index + 1].startNumber = $scope.pages.items[index].endNumber + 1;
    else
        $scope.totalPage = $scope.pages.items[index].endNumber;
};
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/60f7v8h4/8/

**Update**: If you want to throw an error when a user clicks on done button, you can do a check if the total page and the end page are same or not.

```
 $scope.autoStartPageNumber = function (index) {
     if(index +1 < $scope.pages.items.length){
       $scope.pages.items[index+1].startNumber=$scope.pages.items[index].endNumber + 1;
     }
     else
             $scope.length=$scope.pages.items[index].endNumber;
    };

             if($scope.length!= $scope.totalPage){
                $scope.errorFlag=true;
            }
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/60f7v8h4/12/

Comment: hmm not exactly what i want to do... i want to validate the total page count vs the page count that is set (whether the total is set by the user or me)

Comment: What exactly you want? You want to throw an error like https://jsfiddle.net/60f7v8h4/9/ ?

Comment: what i want to do is to calculate the page counts using the start and end page and compare it to the total pages and throw an error when the user tries to validate

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/60f7v8h4/11/ ?

Comment: @jeremy Why did you remove the answer?

Comment: because this solution isnt really "validating" the errors. it's just "showing" the error message. i was looking for a solution which "validates" the form to check the total page counts.

Comment: What do you mean by validate the form? And in your edit for your question you meant "throw an error"?

Comment: See if this condition  if($scope.length!= $scope.totalPage) , if this is true then make  $scope.pageForm.$invalid=true; .